# How can I get absolute path to a script executed via ${PATH} in bash?

Tags: bash

I would like to get the absolute path to an executed script.
Its path is /use/local/lib/debugger.sh.
And it is called through $PATH=/use/local/lib from another folder.
I searched an example script and found following one.

```
echo "path = $(cd $(dirname $0) && pwd)"
```

I expected I can get the absolute path, /use/local/lib. But the result was not what I expected. I got the absolute path to the  directory where the script is called.

How can I get the absolute path where the script exist?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the `-P` option to `pwd` would make sure symlinks (if any) in the `dirname` of the script are properly resolved:

```
path=$(cd $(dirname $0) && pwd -P)
```

Comment: This is a help, but it doesn't solve what OP wants

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
#!/bin/bash

path="path = $(cd $(dirname $0) && pwd)"
script_name="${0##*/}"

echo "${path}/${script_name}"
```

Or in "oneliner" style `echo "path = $(cd $(dirname $0) && pwd)/${0##*/}"`

Answer (score 1):

If it is really in your $PATH then the "which" command should find it.